# Recursive issue with toString in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I write XML DSL with Kotlin and have faced with a problem. Code:

```
abstract class Element(val name: String) {

    var children = mutableListOf<Element>()

    override fun toString() = """
        <$name>
            ${children.joinToString("\n") { toString() }}
        </$name>
    """.trimIndent()

}
```

I have the following error on `{ toString() }`:

> Type checking has run into a recursive problem. Easiest workaround: specify types of your declarations explicitly.

I need the following output:

```
<a>
    <b>
    </b>
    <c>
    </c>
</a>
```

If I have the following code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a = Element("a")
    a.children.add(Element("b"))
    a.children.add(Element("c"))
    println(a)
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you called `toString` from the lambda argument of `joinToString` function, you did not specify the receiver of that `toString`. In that case the implicit receiver `this` in the scope is used. That `this` points to the parent element rather than the current child, so you're making a recursive call.

Inside that lambda you should access child element with the implicit parameter name `it`, or name the parameter explicitly.

```
children.joinToString("\n") { it.toString() }
children.joinToString("\n") { child -> child.toString() }
```

However this won't make the recursive type checking problem go away, because here the same `toString` is referenced inside its body, the type of which is yet to be inferred. To break this kind of recursion you need to specify the return type of `toString` explicitly.

```
override fun toString(): String = ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I have `StackOverflowError`, but I think that's another story ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a total novice with Kotlin, so this not may be very idiomatic. It works, though.

```
class Element(val name: String) {

    var children = mutableListOf<Element>()

    private fun recursiveToString(depth: Int): String {
        fun tabulations(amount: Int) = "\t".repeat(amount)
        val childrenAsString: String = children.joinToString("") {
            tabulations(depth + 1) + it.recursiveToString(depth + 1) 
        }
        return "<$name>\n$childrenAsString${tabulations(depth)}</$name>\n"
}

    override fun toString() = recursiveToString(0)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a = Element("a")
    a.children.add(Element("b"))
    val c = Element("c")
    c.children.add(Element("d"))
    a.children.add(c)
    println(a)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I would recommend you to read about [String interpolation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#string-interpolation).